# Separating reaction to home button from back button on root activity

Tags: android

In my android app, I've created a return notification which I start in a service from the onStop() function of my root activity. It works fine but I want it to work only for the home button and not for back button [which gives a dialog option to leave the app and leaves an annoying notification service running]

Answer (score 1):

You could set a flag when `onBackPressed()` is called which you can then check in `onStop()` to see if the back button was used to leave the app, otherwise, it's the home button. Just don't forget to unflag it in `onStart()` or similar.

Comment: Thanks but I also have an exit function in my menu which moves the stack to the background and essentially leaves the app

Answer (score 0):

I decided to start the return service with the app and turn it off when i leave via onBackPressed() or menu. this way the return notification and the service remain when the app is exited and disappear when the system or the user close the application.

here is how I close the service and notification

activity.stopService(new Intent("gideon.guide.services.ReturnService"));
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(1);

here is how I exit the app mind you android doesn't support direct closing of the app it is not completely finished

activity.moveTaskToBack(true);